# Getting profile information on Google + via Android App

Tags: android, google-plus

I've been working on Google sign-in in Android Apps and I've got it working. The problem appears when I try to retrieve profile information. In the API guide in Android developers:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

They explain the way to do it using the function "loadPerson" and the listener "OnPersonLoadedListener". I'm getting an error in Eclipse that says that function is undefined. If you look up into the reference of the PlusClient Class (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html), neither loadPerson nor OnPersonLoadedListener appear. And I've found a link to OnPersonLoadedListener:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener.html

But it's getting 404 Error.

Am I missing something? Is it deprecated? I'm quite confused :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [GetCurrentPerson](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#getCurrentPerson%28%29) - this will get you the profile information for the currently signed in user. Are you trying to do something different like look up a user's Google+ profile or get the list of the people they have made visible to your app?

Comment: That should probably be updated in the Google+ developer docs though :) https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to retrieve, user's name and so on. I didn't know about that method, I will give it a try thanks a lot :D

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the method I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that method is now deprecated and for some reason the documentation is missing.
Check this, I believe that's what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener.html

Comment: I just need user information. OnPeopleLoadedListener is used to retrieve information about people in user's circles isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that listener is used for the API call, plus.people.list: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list